# Some questions about AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As far as I understand in an AsyncTask only *doInBackground* is executed in its own task. All other methods - e.g. *onPostExecute* - are executed in the Activity task.
Is it true, that *onPostExecute* and let's say *onCofigurationChanged* are in fact synchronized?

Does the system clean up a task, if it is finished or canceled and no longer referenced?

Answer (score 3):

Both `onPostExecute` and `onConfigurationChanged` are executed on the "UI thread" therefore executed one after another (in any order). There's a single UI Thread per application.

As with any Java object garbage collector eventually cleans up `AsyncTask` if it's no longer referenced.